# jQuery dataTables not updates even after changing the data of each row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've a Table which uses JQUERY datatable plugin. The first column of the table is actually the serial number which am binding using the **render** option in **columndef** option and my table initilisation is as below.

```
      var myTable = $("#table_question").dataTable(
        {
            "columnDefs": [
            { "targets": 0, "render": 
function (data, type, row,meta) { return String.format("<h4>{0}</h4>",row[4] ) } },

            { "targets": [3, 4], "visible": false}],

            "lengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, 100, -1], [10, 20, 50, 100, "All"]],

        });
```

And here is the HTML structure of my **TR** (Mine is an ASP.NET app so included the eval there)

```
<tr questionid='<%# Eval("questionid")%>' questiontype='<%# Eval("questiontype")%>'>
   <td class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 xol-sm-1">
   </td>
   <td class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
      <%# Eval("question")%>
   </td>
   <td class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
      <%# Eval("questionid")%>
   </td>
   <td>
      <%# Eval("questiontype") %>
   </td>
   <td> <%# Eval("questionsequence")%></td>
</tr>
```

Everything working fine. Serial number is showing fine. but when I delete a row I need to update the serial number. So I tried to iterate over the table and changed the Row data. But nothing seems to be reflecting on the table when I tried using the following way.

```
var table = $('#table_question').DataTable();
table.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
     var row = this.data();
     row[0]=7
     row[4]=7;
});

table.draw(true);
```

here datatable data changes (I think), but its not getting reflect on the table

Comment: Does it reflect once you `refresh` the page? I mean if any server side processing is involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to set the row data back, after you have edited the array :

```js
this.data(row).draw();
```

`this.data()` just returns a "stupid" array, dataTables cannot be aware of changes to the array before it is reinserted.

your code in action -> **http://jsfiddle.net/cfqytLso/**

Comment: THank you very much.. It worked fine.. but a little clarification regarding rowIdx. Actually my purpose of the above code is to reset back the serial number on the first column when a row deletes. So in your jsfiddle code I replaced 7 with rowIdx which worked fine. but in my local code when I tried to use rowIdx it returns an error
"DataTables warning: table id=table_question - Requested unknown parameter '4' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4"
the code I tried was row[0]=rowIdx;

Comment: Sorry.. I found the bug. The plugin version I was using is 1.10.6. I updated to 1.10.9 and it fixed the bug. I think that parameter in every function is not available in previous version

Comment: @sforsandeep, I think you are right. Great you got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this like so

```
  this.data().fieldYouWantToModify = newValue;
  this.invalidate().draw();
```

> Since you are not changing how the cell is rendered, you don't need to rerender.

I found the solution [here](https://m.datatables.net/forums/discussion/42823/row-draw-not-updating-row)